# how to retrieve form variables using tidesdk + php?

Tags: php, forms, tidesdk

i'm using TideSdk + PHP for my project, but i can't retrieve post variables with $_POST.
any way to do this ?

Comment: Hello ! Can you post an example of your code here so we can stand exactly on your problem !

Answer (score 3):

This example is a bit stale but shows you how to work with form content:

http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2011/01/03/introduction-to-creating-desktop-applications-with-php-and-titanium/

Comment: Thanks a lot sir,
the answer was there, in fact TideSdk treat both "get" and "post" variables in the same way with $_GET