# TideSDK $_GET retrieval shows null

Tags: php, get, tidesdk

This was asked [literally two weeks ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702381/how-to-retrieve-form-variables-using-tidesdk-php), I'm sorry, but I must be doing something wrong.

I've got:

```
<form action="action.php">
    <input type="text" name="bar" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go!" />
</form>
```

And in the corresponding action.php,

```
<script type='text/php'>
    $test = $_GET['bar'];

    if ($_GET['submit']) {
        $message = 'OK';

    }

    else {
        $message = 'No';
    }

</script>

<script>
    document.write(test);
    document.write(message);
</script>
```

The results are `"Null"` and `"No"` -- `$_GET['bar']` is interpreted as `empty` (when it's not), and even `$_GET['submit']` doesn't even return `true` (when I arrived at the page by clicking on the `'submit'` button).

This is *exactly* the implementation outlined by the [solution given](http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2011/01/03/introduction-to-creating-desktop-applications-with-php-and-titanium/)....right?

Does this no longer work with TideSDK? What am I missing here? If this isn't possible to accomplish in PHP & TideSDK, what's the best way I go about passing calculated or user-entered parameters from one page to another? Thanks everyone.

[note -- I copy/pasted the code in so some omissions/inconsistencies should be gone now. sorry about that!]

Comment: using `<script type='text/php'>` for start php is a bad idea. do tidesdk force you to do so?

Comment: Yeah, it seems like this is what TideSDK requires. It hasn't been as smooth as just writing PHP and plopping it in; there are some differences in implementation.

Comment: What does var_dump($_GET); shows.

Comment: I got it, but I can't post it as an answer yet. It *was* some quirk of TideSDK I wasn't understanding...In TideSDK, external PHP sometimes *requires* <?php and ?> tags, and sometimes *requires* that they be omitted. In the case of include() or direct navigation (such as form action.php), they are required. I'll post in more detail after 8 hours so I can close this one up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've got the answer.

It *was* a quirk of TideSDK I had wrong and not in the PHP itself. Per the [TideSDK Guide to Using PHP](http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/guide/using_php)

In Tide, if you include a PHP file using one of the two methods (<script src="..." type="text/php">), you *must* omit the <?php and ?> tags.

Other methods — using the request or include functions or directly navigating to a php file (which includes form action .php files), require the start and end tags in the file.

I didn't have those, because I thought I was doing something where they had to be omitted. Despite that, it didn't **break**, as the syntax was functional — just the PHP preprocessing ability was not there and all the $_GET variables I was expecting, were empty. Because of that, I didn't catch on to the possibility that my method of including the PHP file was wrong.

Thanks to everyone who spent time helping me on this, and especially to [silentboy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2193789/silentboy), who asked me to use var_dump, which got me thinking about why var_dump, echo, etc don't work with TideSDK, except <?php and ?> tags.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to give foo as field in form and also give submit button a name.Probably by changing your form will give you the desired results.

```
<form action="action.php" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="foo" value="1234" /> 
        <input type="text" name="bar" />
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Go!" />
    </form>
```

In php you need to write like this:

```
<?php
$test = $_GET['bar'];


if ($_GET['submit']) {
    $message = 'OK';

}

else {
    $message = 'No';
    }


    echo $test;
    echo $message;
?>
```

I am not sure php is installed at your place or not.

If You want to make it in javascript use the below one:

```
<script>
//$test = $_GET['bar'];
function getParameterByName(name)
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
  if(results == null)
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

if (getParameterByName("submit")) {
    message = 'OK';

}

else {
    message = 'No';
    }

</script>
<script>
    document.write(getParameterByName("foo"));
    document.write(message);
</script>
```

Comment: Definitely 4AM here, haha. I did ask for 'bar' in my code instead of foo, but in either case, it's still returning Null and No. Are my issues not reproducible?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input type="submit" value="Go!" />
```

Where is the name "**submit**" for  `$_GET['submit']` ?

**use**      `<input type="submit"  name ="you" value="Go!" />` 
 **then askfor**  `$_GET['you']`

**its Easy to check**

```
if (isset($_GET['bar']))
{
  $message = 'OK';
}
```

Comment: Oh, that's my bad. I did have the name="submit" in there. I had a few typos in there, should have just copy/pasted.

Comment: yeah - checking isset doesn't return "OK". Which makes me think it's some quirk of TideSDK I'm not aware of. Thanks for all your help so far, though!

Comment: <script type='text/php'> is bad use <?php ?>